# Can't compile program when `opencv(c++)` code is added in vs Code

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, gcc

This is my program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<D:\installation folder\opencv\build\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
Mat image;//**LOOK HERE**---(1)
// if ( !image.data )
// {
//     printf("No image data \n");
//     return -1;
// }
// namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
// imshow("Display Image", image);
// waitKey(0);

cout << "executed" << endl;
return 0;

}
```

Whenever I comment `line-(1)`, program is compiled and ran successfully. But whenever I uncomment any opencv-code inside `main()` program is not compiled and vsCode shows error like

> main.exe doesn't exists.

I don't know where is the problem. I am new in openCV.
I am using `vsCode` and `gcc-compiler`.
If you need more info, let me know in comment

Extra:`task.json`

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "D:\\installation folder\\mingw64\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "-I",
            "D:\\installation folder\\OpenCV-MinGW-Build-OpenCV-4.5.5-x64\\include",
            "-L",
            "D:\\installation folder\\OpenCV-MinGW-Build-OpenCV-4.5.5-x64\\x64\\mingw\\bin",
            "-llibopencv_calib3d411",
            "-llibopencv_core411",
            "-llibopencv_dnn411",
            "-llibopencv_features2d411",
            "-llibopencv_flann411",
            "-llibopencv_highgui411",
            "-llibopencv_imgcodecs411",
            "-llibopencv_imgproc411",
            "-llibopencv_ml411",
            "-llibopencv_objdetect411",
            "-llibopencv_photo411",
            "-llibopencv_stitching411",
            "-llibopencv_video411",
            "-llibopencv_videoio411"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "D:\\installation folder\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "D:\\installation folder\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
]
```

}

Terminal:
[image: terminal screen]

Comment: Are you linking against opencv? What is the output of the compiler/build config?

Comment: ***main.exe doesn't exists.*** It won't if your build failed.

Comment: don't use absolute paths in `#include` use a compiler flag to define include directories

Comment: @Lala5th `D:\projects\opencvTest/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'`

Comment: `#include<D:\installation folder\opencv\build\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp>` probably is a bad step. You may want to use msys2 to install your mingw and use the package manager in msys2 to install opencv binaries that are compatible with mingw. The official VSCode documentation even recommends using msys2: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: @rioV8 include directories doesn't even work with normal c++ code. Idk

Comment: ***undefined reference to cv::Mat::~Mat()'*** Show how you edited your `tasks.json` to link to the opencv linbraries.

Comment: general C++: **don't use `using namespace`**, always type the namespace used

Comment: @drescherjm I have added `task.json` in queston

Comment: don't add the compiler default include and lib path to compile command, do this for the OpenCV location

Comment: Show tour terminal output. I suspect you are using the wrong task to build.

Comment: @rioV8 not working after using `cv::Mat`

Comment: @drescherjm I have added picture. `Program runs when i comment line(1)`

Comment: It looks like I was correct. `"C/C++: g++.exe build active file"` is being executed instead of  `"g++.exe build active file"` so its not using any of your linker settings.

Comment: How to fix this? :(